# KafkaStreams: access KTable value before updating

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'am consuming Data from Topic and write it to the table:

```
final KStream<String, AuftragGemeindeschluessel> myStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(
                sabKafkaProperties.getAuftragGemeindeSchluesselTopicName(),
                Consumed.with(
                                org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.String(),
                                Serdes.getMyObjectSerde())
                        .withName("AUFTRAG_GEMEINDESCHLUESSEL"));

 myStream.toTable(Named.as("MY_STATE_STORE"), getMaterializedViewForStateStore());
```

I always have a same key, which means that a new value always overwrites the old value in my KTable, but I have to compare old and new values first.

How could i do this?

Comment: You need to use Processor API and get the value from the state store

Comment: thx, could you post any code snippet, i'am usually using dsl and not Processor API

Comment: i've tried to build my topology like this:
stream -> processorNode -> toTable.
In the init-method of processorNode (AbstractProcessor) i'am trying to get a stateStore from context and i get exception: 
Processor KSTREAM has no access to StateStore MY_STATE_STORE as the store is not connected to the processor. If you add stores manually via '.addStateStore()' make sure to connect the added store to the processor by providing the processor name to '.addStateStore()' or connect them via '.connectProcessorAndStateStores()'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried and the full error

Comment: i could fix it. I've created ValueTransformer with DSL. In this ValueTransformer i've fetched data from keyValueStore. Few lines later i've used: store.put(key, value). 
So i access to the value, before it has been overwritten.

Comment: Feel free to provide solution below as a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

my solution for this problem, looks like this:

```
public class MyValueTransformer implements ValueTransformer{

    private KeyValueStore<String, MyObject> stateStore;
    
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        stateStore = context.getStateStore(STATE_STORE_NAME);
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<OtherObject> transform(OtherObj currentObj) {            
            //fetch last saved value from store
            final OtherObj otherObj = stateStore.get("myKey");
            /*
            * do some logik for computing current state-store value, before it will be overwritten with "toTable"
            */
            
            //save 
            stateStore.put("myKey", currentObj);

        return new ArrayList();
    }
}
```